# Getting "Cannot read property 'key' of undefined" in vue template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

So in my vue I have a method that takes some data, creates arrays and passes them to another vue file for rendering in the template.

The method

```
        this.shoesData.titles = ['Date', 'Model', 'Price Qty', 'Order Qty', 'Discount Qty'];
        this.shoesData.values = [ 
          new Date(this.getShoes.insertDate).toISOString().slice(0, 10).toString(),
          this.getShoes.model,
          parseFloat(this.getShoes.price).toFixed(0).toString()+' tn', 
          parseFloat(this.getShoes.order).toFixed(0).toString()+' tn',
          parseFloat(this.getShoes.discount).toFixed(0).toString()+' tn'
        ];
```

and then I pass `shoesData` to another file to use it in its template

```
<CardMultiValue v-if="shoesData.values"  :cardData="shoesData"  />
```

in `CardMultiValue`  I have,

```
<template>
<v-card style="width:100%;height:100%;" :flat="flat" >          
    <v-card-title class="title" v-if="cardData.Title" style="width:100%;height:30px;justify-content:center;align-items:center;padding:5px;">{{cardData.Title}}</v-card-title>
    <v-card-actions  v-if="cardData.Title" style='width:100%;height:calc(100% - 30px);padding:5px;' >
        <v-container style="padding:0px;height:100%;">                     
            <v-row style="height:100%;">
                <v-col :cols="8">
                    <div v-for="title in cardData.titles" :key="title" :style="'display:flex;align-items:center;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;height:'+rowHeight+'%;'">
                        {{title}}
                    </div>
                </v-col> 
                <v-col :cols="4">                        
                    <div v-for="value in cardData.values" :key="value" :style="'display:flex;align-items:center;font-size:18px;height:'+rowHeight+'%;'">
                        {{value}}
                    </div>
                </v-col>  
            </v-row>   
        </v-container>
    </v-card-actions> 
    <v-card-actions  v-else style='width:100%;height:100%;padding:5px;' > 
        <v-container style="padding:0px;height:100%;">                     
            <v-row style="height:100%;">
                <v-col :cols="8">
                    <div v-for="a in cardData.titles" :key="a" :style="'display:flex;align-items:center;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;height:'+rowHeight+'%;'">
                        {{a}}
                    </div>
                </v-col> 
                <v-col :cols="4">
                    <div v-for="b in cardData.values" :key="b" :style="'display:flex;align-items:center;font-size:18px;height:'+rowHeight+'%;'">
                        {{b}}
                    </div>
                </v-col>  
            </v-row>   
        </v-container>
    </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```

This is not something complicated, and yet, if `this.getShoes.order` and `this.getShoes.discount` both happen to be 0 , I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
    at sameVnode (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5811)
    at updateChildren (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6213)
    at patchVnode (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6313)
    at updateChildren (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6187)
    at patchVnode (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6313)
    at updateChildren (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6187)
    at patchVnode (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6313)
    at updateChildren (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6187)
    at patchVnode (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6313)
    at updateChildren (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6187)
```

This must be a template error, because if I completely remove `this.getShoes.order` or `this.getShoes.discount` I get no error. Also, if I dont pass the data to `CardMultiValue` I get no error.

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: what is `this.getShoes`?

Comment: @JaromandaX Check the comment I made in the anser below. It also ansers your question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**this.getshoes** sounds like a method name. So, perhaps change it to this.getShoes().price or pass the appropriate paramters, if there are any, to it; this.getShoes(someParameter).price

Comment: This is a vuex getter, it does `getshoes: state => state.shoes`. State.shoes gets data from a get request. Contains data like `price:25, order:40, discount:0`. So, I m just passing that data, as soon as they are available. Thanks